# React Native SectionList scroll to section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just changed my ListView to React Native's new SectionList and now the app crashes when I attempt to use the scrollTo function, stating that it's undefined. I tried looking up new/alternative functions that may help, but none of them seem to be working.

What's the proper protocol for programmatically scrolling to a specific section with the new SectionList?

Links I've been consulting thus far:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13151
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/virtualizedlist.html#scrolltoend

My current attempt:

```
var params = {animated:true,offset:Platform.OS == "ios" ? 244 : 264}
_mainListView.scrollToOffset(params)
```

Comment: It's been 2 days. Any luck so far?

Comment: @jpls93 Still no luck, looks like there's some merged branches on GitHub that add scrollTo functions for SectionList but they aren't part of the release

Comment: perhaps we could look into `VirtualizedList`'s `scrollTo` `props` instead?

Comment: @jpls93 Do you know how to add sections to VirtualizedList?

Comment: Maybe this is what we're looking for [scrollToItem/scrollToIndex/scrollToOffset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3e7aa5f14e0064c5e142b810829019027c52d6eb/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L189)

Comment: @jpls93 Yes those are fine functions but they only seem to be for VirtualizedList and FlatList, not SectionList

Comment: How about this one? [SectionList scrollToItem or scrollToOffset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/eeddef18b8d3d624ae8027104790c963bdc586be/Libraries/Lists/SectionList.js#L241)

Comment: @jpls93 I tried that, but it doesn't appear to be merged with the current release

Comment: @jpls93 it looks like react native JUST last night released .45 as the stable release which has scrollToLocation enabled on sectionList, I have had lots of performance problems with it tho.

Comment: @Radeng Thanks for the update! Performance problems on both iOS and Android?

Comment: @jpls93 performance problems for both flatlist and sectionlist, with both rendering and scrolling methods for large ~1000 item list. Worse performance than on .44 imo. Only been building for ios so idk about andriod.

Answer (score 8):

```
<SectionList
          ref={(sectionList) => { this.sectionList = sectionList }} .../>

this.sectionList.scrollToLocation(
        {
          sectionIndex: sectionIndex,
          itemIndex: itemIndex
        }
      );
```

This is what I used to get it working using a mix of this post and https://snack.expo.io/HJp9mEQkG

Answer (score 4):

This is how I scroll to end

```js
listRef.current?.scrollToLocation({
  animated: true,
  sectionIndex: sections.length - 1,
  itemIndex: sections[sections.length - 1].data.length - 1,
})
```

This is how I scroll to top

```js
listRef.current?.scrollToLocation({
  animated: true,
  sectionIndex: 0,
  itemIndex: 0,
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scrollToSection = (sectionIndex,itemIndex = 1 ) => {
 this.refs.foo.scrollToLocation({
      sectionIndex: sectionIndex,
      itemIndex: itemIndex
    });
}
```

sectionList:

```
<SectionList
 ref = "foo",
 //something
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me workaround is

```
list.current?.getScrollResponder()?.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0, animated: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

SectionList scroll to end

```
const [listViewHeight, setListViewHeight] = useState(undefined);

<SectionList
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
      sections={sectionListData}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}


onLayout={event => {
        setListViewHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)
}}
onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => {
        scrollViewRef?.current?.getScrollResponder()?.scrollTo({
          y: h - listViewHeight
        })
}}
```